# Angular directive transclude <tr> breaks layout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to transclude a table row (a) in a ng-repeat loop so that another table row (b) can be shown/hidden when a user clicks (a). Both table rows are rendering, however, the `<ng-transclude>` element - needed to include (a) before (b), in the directive template, is breaking the layout. How can I use a directive to render two table rows without breaking the layout?

// main template

```
<tr id="a" campaign-item ng-if="vm.campaignData.length > 0" ng-repeat="campaign in vm.campaignData | orderBy:vm.sortBy:vm.sortReverse | filter:searchCampaigns track by $index" ng-click="vm.showCampaignPreview(campaign)">
    <td>{{ campaign.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.priority }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.status }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.creator }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.approver }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.release_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.expiration_date }}</td>
    <td><select ng-init="campaignOptions = vm.campaignOptions[0]" name="campaignOption" class="form-control" ng-model="campaignOptions" ng-options="campaign.name for campaign in vm.campaignOptions track by campaign.value"></select></td>
</tr>
```

// directive

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('vsmsCampaignModule')
.directive('campaignItem', campaign)

    function campaign(){

        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'EA',
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/vsms/admin/campaign/campaign.tpl.html'
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, el, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
            // do something with clone compiled and linked
            // in child scope of directive's scope:
        }

    }

})();
```

// directive template

```
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>

<tr id="b">
    <td colspan="8">{{ campaign.description }}</td>
    <td colspan="8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="package in campaign.packages">
                        {{ package.name }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">{{ campaign.policy }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">{{ campaign.region }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="vehicle in campaign.vehicles">
                        {{ vehicle.name }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

// update, I solved the issue by simply using ng-repeat-start/end

```
<tr ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-if="vm.campaignData.length > 0" ng-repeat-start="campaign in vm.campaignData | orderBy:vm.sortBy:vm.sortReverse | filter:searchCampaigns track by campaign.id" ng-click="vm.showCampaignPreview(campaign)">
    <td>{{ campaign.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.priority }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.status }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.creator }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.approver }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.release_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.expiration_date }}</td>
    <td>
        <select ng-init="campaignOptions = vm.campaignOptions[0]" name="campaignOption" class="form-control" ng-model="campaignOptions" ng-options="campaign.name for campaign in vm.campaignOptions track by campaign.value">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="campaign-preview" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-repeat-end ng-show="vm.selectedCampaign == campaign.id">
    <td colspan="8">{{ campaign.description }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I highly suspect that you are trying to render a `tr` inside of another `tr`, which is not valid HTML.

Comment: That's invalid html .... `<table>` is limited on allowed children. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I basically want to transclude the tr (a) into the directive template before tr (b) i.e., replace the ng-transclude element with the tr (a). I tried using replace: true but I get this error: "Template for directive 'campaignItem' must have exactly one root element."

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by simply using ng-repeat-start/end (see update above) instead of a directive.

Answer (score 0):

It will require you to rethink your directives a bit but you can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to render several `TR`s per each `ng-repeat` iteration, like that:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="vehicle in campaign.vehicles" 
     ng-click='vehicle.showDetails = !!!vehicle.showDetails'>
   <td> {{ vehicle.name }} </td>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show='vehicle.showDetails'>
   <td> {{ vehicle.details }}
   </td>                        
 </tr>
```